# как реализовать "ps ax | grep init" на C

Tags: linux, unix

я очень плохо разбираюсь в Linux, но мне нужно решить единственную задачу, ответ на которую я не могу найти в интернете, пожалуйста, помогите

не могли бы вы привести пример, как можно связать команды ps и grep на С? мне нужно написать на C "ps ax | grep init", но я плохо понимаю, как правильно реализовать это

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, наверное:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE * ff;
    char buf[1024];

    ff = popen("ps ax | grep init", "r");
    if (ff == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, 1024, ff) ) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
}
```